# IRM x Workflow in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: designer-workflow, irm

Are there any restrictions on using a workflow in a library with IRM enabled?

I'm using SharePoint Online 2013.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Can you be a little more specific?

The most common use case for IRM I know revolves around a workflow, expiration. Once an item meets an expiration limit, say created date plus 1 year, it executes a workflow to delete the item or move it to another location.

Comment: I try set a value to a column in the item